# Can't set Context in Provider Hosted App

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-rest-api, provider-hosted-app

I'm trying to get access to context in a provider hosted Sharepoint App, so that I can use the following to move folders via javascript:

```
SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder(context,currentFolder,destinationFolder);
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){},function(){});
```

When the app  is initialized I get an access token I used to make rest queries with no problem and I also get the SPHostWebUrl as a query string parameter (I don't get a SPAppWebUrl in the query string).

Here is how I was trying to get the correct context (I am using the SPHostWebUrl instead of SPAppWebUrl), but it always triggers the error:

```
    var spHostWebUrl =decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostWebUrl"));
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(spHostWebUrl);
    var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(spHostWebUrl);
    ctx.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    var web = ctx.get_web();

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function () {
     alert("sucess"); },
     function (a, b) {
     alert("error"); }
    );
```

Comment: forgot to load the web: `ctx.load(web);` Also check this link out: https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/cross-domain-and-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-csom/